# VBA custom class, get all objects by property value

Tags: excel, class, object, vba

I have a Class - "Class1" with an attribute - "attribute1" as string.
Possible vlaues of this attribute are {1, 2}

**Class1 Module**

```
   Private pattribute1 As String

   Public Property Get attribute1 () As String
       attribute1 = pattribute1 
   End Property

   Public Property Let attribute1 (Value As String)
       pattribute1 = Value
   End Property
```

In my main program, I need to retrieve all the objects with attribute1 value equal to {1}.

**Main Module**

```
   Dim col As New Collection 

   'Create objects 
   Do While j <= 5

       Dim obj As Class1
       Set obj= New Class1
       if j<3 then 
           obj.attribute1 = "1"
       else 
           obj.attribute1 = "2"
       end if
       j = j + 1
   Loop

   Set col = 'get all objects from Class1 with attribute equal to "1"
```

Which is the most efficient way to do this?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: please share your current code and we will gladly help

Comment: if possible values of your attribute are 1,2, 3  is it not better to use an int or an enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code in your `Main` module to the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestClass1()

Dim col() As New Class1
Dim obj As Class1
Dim j As Long
Dim id As Long

ReDim col(0 To 100) '<-- init to large size, will optimize later

'Create objects
Do While j <= 5
    Set obj = New Class1
    If j < 3 Then
        obj.attribute1 = "1"
        Set col(id) = obj '<-- add to col when equals 1
        id = id + 1
    Else
        obj.attribute1 = "2"
    End If
    j = j + 1
    Set obj = New Nothing
Loop

ReDim Preserve col(0 To id - 1) '<-- resize array to populated size

End Sub
```

Comment: This works fine. But my first thought was to build a function inside my class1 that accepts an argument like "1" or "2". Is this possible?

Comment: @gematzab  it's possible